# Is there a way of looping trough elements with a certain class name in svelte

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to create a nice animation effect with javascript based on someones tutorial.

The issue is that i would need to do a for loop where i use getElementsByClassName() but in svelte you cannot access DOM the regular way. I am still a beginner with svelte and the whole frontend web development.

Someone suggested that i could use something like:

```js
export let className = '';
export {className as Class};
```

But this gave me an error so i gave up on it.

I know about `bind:this` but it does not work how i want it to.

Comment: It's not that you can't access the DOM the regular way, usually you shouldn't. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Corrl I want to loop trough elements with a certain class and change their style.

Comment: That's what you said in the title. Without giving more information what effect your are after or sharing some code it's hard to tell what might be a better way to achieve it in Svelte without querying the DOM.

Comment: Please provide a link to the tutorial you're following, and provide a runnable snippet with the vanilla javascript you want to sveltify. This question is akin to asking which highway to drive along in your airplane

Comment: @ZachJensz here is the tutorial i am following: https://piped.kavin.rocks/watch?v=yu0Cm4BqQv0 it's around 2:45